# Two tables containing the same column..want to retrieve information from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

STAFF and PROJECTS

When a staff account is created via a form they must enter a staffid

When a staff member is logged into the system they can upload a project to the projects table via a form.

When they submit the form the staffid of the currently logged in staff member is saved to the staffid column within the projects table

What I want to do is be able to show in the 'View Projects' page the first name and surname of the staff member who CREATED the project however, I only have the staffid saved to the PROJECTS table and the firstname and surname of the staff member is within the STAFF table.

projects table

```
ID | title | description | uploadfile | multiple | staffid
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Pro1  |   info      |    .doc    |    Y     | 6565
2  | Pro2  |    info     |  doc   |    Y     | 6575
3  | Pro3  |    info     |   doc  |    Y     | 3355
```

staff table

```
ID | firstname | surname | staffid   
------------------------------------
1  | Barbra    |  Doe    |    6565  
2  | Ronnie    |  Doe    |    6575  
3  | Simon     |  Doe    |    3355
```

what is the best and possible way to achieve this, and also how to inject the PHP code to display the SQL results?

Comment: Don't apologize for being an amateur. We all started somewhere and SO is a great resource to learn.

Comment: I think a half hour with any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be beneficial at this stage

Comment: `select projects.title,staff.firstname,staff.surname from projects left join staff on projects.staffid = staff.staffid`

Answer (score 4):

You can query throught the `project` table and make join on staffid to get `firstname` and `lastname` from staff `table`

I have written a query in sql-server so there might be any syntax changes when writing it for my sql

```
select title, description, s.firstname, s.surename multiple 
from project p
inner join staff s on s.staffid = p.staffid
```

Comment: thanks for your comment reply I'm testing this now.. View Projects page would i just echo something like this  echo "<td>".$row['s.firstname']."</td>"; or is that incorrect way to obtain that value

Comment: @shanlikestrains no issues . You can directly run on your database ide

Comment: I can't seem to get it to display first and surname in my view projects table

Comment: cool. saved hours of effort. thanks.